# What is the density of air inside an electric arc?

Tags: electricity

It seems to me that at least after (but I would guess it happens also just before) ionized air allows conduction of a current, there is an elevated mechanical tension along the molecules forming the arc, thus augmenting density as well as the overall conductance of the circuit. I would be very surprised the local density does not change, but in any case, if someone could give a more definite answer, ideally argumented with examples of numbers, that would be nice.
Side note: please consider the question about what makes up the arc and not a litteral definition of the word "air". Also, I am obviously more interested to know about the maximum density in the vicinity of the arc, not about gradients, if any, although more details are welcome.

Comment: Well, actually the arc is heating the gases so they expand, lowering the density in the arc.

Comment: OK interesting. By how much and does it lead to a loss of conductivity if heat makes molecules too far apart?

Comment: You have free electrons and ions. Consider the Paschen  curve for air/gas breakdown. Also consider the hazards of an arc flash.

Comment: Thanks for redirecting me to Paschen law, the Wikipedia article is rich in information.